# can a JRI(Java/R Interface) program in a JAR file run on a system that doesn't have R installed?

Tags: java, r, jri, rjava

If a JRI(Java/R Interface) program uses R to display a graph, can it be bundled into a jar and run on a system without R?

Comment: Needed to Google it myself :D http://www.rforge.net/JRI/

Answer (score 3):

No. It cannot. `JRI` needs to be linked against `R`. This is a low-level interface.

You could adopt some client/server design where you would use `Rserve` on the server and classes of the `REngine` API on the client so that your client machine does not need `R`.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do that. I did copy all the required dlls into Java Project and add them to native libraries.and then copy a base folder from R installation in library. set R_HOME to the folder containing library base. it will work

Comment: Thats sound very interesting, could you expan, and give some examples on that, im having similsr issues with deploying Jri + java programs.

Comment: Dave if you are having trouble with JRI try to check whether you have included the JRI.DLL in the native lib. Also you can use dependency walker to find out what dll are missing. But this thread is about using JRI without installing R. Are you trying to do the same?

Comment: Hi Satyam, could you view my question in :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683112/includeing-the-jri-dll-in-the-native-lib-java-r-interface ?